# logon and then access another page with the same session cookies using curl

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl, authentication

I looked at different seemingly similar questions but can't seem to understand it and also can't get it to work at all.

Situation: I have an external website from where I can download data and files. In order to download these, I first need to log in.

I want to automate this process so that I can login and download certain data files that are needed daily with one click. However, I don't know how to do it in cURL and have not found the right solution for this so far.

Here is my code that I have right now: (this covers only the login procedure so far, and I have no clue if it even logs in. I just know that I would probably see it when the cookies are stored, but there are none in the cookie.txt)

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com/login.jsp";
$postfields = "userId=abc&password=123";

$logon = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($logon, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($logon, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($logon, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($logon, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($logon, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($logon, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($logon, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$result = curl_exec($logon);
curl_close($logon);

echo file_get_contents("cookie.txt");
```

This returns nothing and the file "cookie.txt" also does not exist. I tried earlier to create a file first by using the following, but then the file is just empty and stays empty.

```
$fp = fopen("cookie.txt","w");
fclose($fp);
```

Anyone can help me with some advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

The `cookie.txt` file is empty because you haven't populated it with any cookie data.

Your best bet is to replace

```
curl_setopt($logon, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($logon, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
```

with

```
$cookiesString = '';
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $value) {
    if (!empty($cookiesString)) {
        $cookiesString  .= ';';
    }
    $cookiesString .= $name . '=' . addslashes($value);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookiesString);
```

Comment: seems logical but I guess there are other things that prevent this from working. I still do not have any cookie.txt file after running this.

Comment: like I said in the answer - there will be no cookie.txt file unless you create it. Why do you want a cookie.txt file so badly?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I don't need a cookie.txt necessarily. I guess I saw this somewhere in another example and thought it is necessary. Okay, in using the above, how will I know that the cookies have been set? Really, right now I just try to find out if my script works at all to logon or if it doesn't. I have been working simple tasks with cURL, but I guess this is still not easy for me to grasp how to work with it this way.

Comment: You should be using Xdebug to step through your code line by line. Then you can inspect the `$cookiesString` variable and see what it contains. You may want to build the `$cookiesString` variable manually from another source, rather than buidling it from the contents of `$_COOKIE` (that might not be populated yet)